# Uninstall VMware Workstation v8.04 completely from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, vmware-workstation

I wanted to uninstall VMware Workstation v8.04 from my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I could not do that from Control Panel. I received "The MSI failed" error like this:
http://www.sysprobs.com/fixed-the-msi-failed-vmware-workstation-uninstall-repair-and-update-in-windows-7

I then followed this link to remove VMware manually:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308

Now whenever I go to Control Panel > Programs and Features, there is no VMware in the list. However when I want to install an older version of VMware (v8.02), the newer version is installed on the system with a uninstall button. When I click on this button I receive this error:

> Bad Arguments for :C\ProgramData\VMware\VMware/Workstation\Uninstaller\uninstall.exe

I tried to install v8.04 again, but I got the same error. I also cleaned up the uninstall with Revo Uninstaller.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have a question about programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer at the end of this tutorial:

[VMware KB: Cleaning up after an incomplete deinstallation on a Windows host](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308)

Two ZIP files have been attached to this article, which you need to run. They clean all registry entries related to VMware from Windows.